# Customize Lint with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, lint

How to write a Gradle Lint check task? Can I run the task from command line and get the lint logs (not from Android Studio)?

For example: in Eclipse, the command may look like:

```
lint --check UnusedResources ~/myproject_path > lint_log.log
```

Then I can find log info in `lint_log.log`. How could this work when I use gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lint` command just executes Android´s Lint CLI (which is a sort of stand-alone-tool which comes with the Android SDK).

But the Android Gradle Plugin (the one you apply with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in your project´s build.gradle) **automatically adds certain lint tasks**.

So there is no need to write own tasks. You can configure a lot of Lint related options with lintOptions. See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support.

To see all available lint tasks just call:
`./gradlew -q tasks | grep lint`

You will see that you have one dedicated task for each build variant.

-> lint will check all variants
-> others tasks will most commonly be lintDebug or lintRelease

Comment: I guess I may get my log from gradlew by command line. Is that true?But I just can not find my gradlew file in my project path. That should be another problem. Thanks a lot. @a11n

Comment: 1. Regarding the log: Yes, it will log some information to the console/command line. But it will also generate comprehensive XML or even HTML reports for you. 2. No gradlew file? Strange. Are you using Android Studio or at least the new Android Build System? https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html#project-structure https://developer.android.com/tools/building/plugin-for-gradle.html